# Creating .JSON file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a basic form that includes an `input` and a submit `button`. I'd like the value of the `input` to be converted into `JSON` and then that `JSON` to be placed in a file on the server for use later. I'm using AJAX and a small `PHP` script to handle the data and the file creation, however the `JSON` file (`test.json`) is never created.

HTML Markup

```
<input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="Page Title"/>
<button type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
var submit = $('#submit');
var title = $('#title');

function createJSON() {
    var jsonObj = [];
    title.each(function() {

        var value = $(this).val();
        var item = {};
        item.title = value;
        jsonObj.push(item);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url:     "create-file.php",
        data: {
            data: jsonObj
        },
        type: "POST"
    });   
}

submit.on('click', function() {
    createJSON();
});
```

PHP (create-file.php)

```
<?php
    $json = $_POST['data'];
    $info = json_encode($json);
    $file = fopen('test.json','w+') or die("File not found");
    fwrite($file, $info);
    fclose($file);
?>
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        title: "Page Title"
    }
]
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I'm not getting an error. The script creates the JSON fine, it gets passed via the AJAX call, and then nothing.

Comment: There has to be an error. Are you sure no file within the script location is created?

Comment: `$json = $_POST['json'];` need to be `$json = $_POST['data'];`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Updated, thanks, but the issue remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `data: {data: jsonObj},` so in php it need to be:-

```
$json = $_POST['data'];
```

Add some error reporting in php page too so that you will get details about error.when all errors are solved then comment those lines.

Do like below:-

```
<?php
    //comment these two lines when errors are resolved
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors',1);

    $json = $_POST['data']; //json need to be data
    $info = json_encode($json);
    $file = fopen('test.json','w+') or die("File not found");
    fwrite($file, $info);
    fclose($file);exit;
?>
```

I have checked it and it's working at my local end

Note:- you have `title.each(function() {` where `title = $('#title');`.

In future if you have more than one text-box then convert `id` to `class` like this:-

```
<input class="title" type="text" name="title" value="Page Title"/>
```

Comment: Yes, my silly `$_POST` error has been rectified, but now the JSON file contains `null` and nothing else?

Comment: @Ryan  glad to help you:):)

Answer (score 2):

Hi You need to write like below code:

```
$json = $_POST['data'];//$_POST['json'];    
$info = json_encode($json);    
$file = fopen('test.json','w+') or die("File not found");
fwrite($file, $info);
fclose($file);
die;
```

it will write json in file test.json like [{"title":"Page Title"}]

Comment: Thanks. This has helped because of my silly `$_POST['data']` error but the written file contains `null` and not the JSON output.