# Submit contents of Textarea in form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am using the `<textarea>` tag in an HTML form to get multiple lines of input from the user. This is my code:

```html
<form action="/submit" id="textArea">
<textarea form="textArea" placeholder="Paste here..." style="width:100%;height:100%;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" style="position:fixed;top:0;right:0;" class="hoverhide">
</form>
```

Whenever I press submit, the text in textarea is not submitted. How can I submit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are submitting a form with php

1. In form you need to use `method='POST'`
2. and give the textarea a name as @EinLinuus mentioned
3. Also you can give name to the input as like `name='submit'`

So your whole code will be like

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']){

$textarea = $_POST['mytext'];

//then your sql query

}

?>

<form action="/submit" method="POST" id="textArea">
<textarea name="mytext" placeholder="Paste here..." style="width:100%;height:100%;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" style="position:fixed;top:0;right:0;" class="hoverhide">
</form>
```

Comment: Note, that you don't have to set the method to POST, if you leave it blank it's GET by default what can be used too.

Comment: Do I have to use SQL? I'd prefer to take the data and store it in a JSON file.

Comment: @UltimateCreeper I think you need to use the SQL or how can you store the data in JSON file

Comment: @UltimateCreeper no, SQL is not required, you can of course do whatever you want. If you want to save it to JSON, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43866886/14427036

Comment: @EinLinuus and UltimateCreeper it was not mentioned for what purpose it needs to be use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the content of the text area from the `$_POST` or `$_GET` variable in PHP, give it a name:

```
<textarea name="mytext"></textarea>
```